# .htaccess file redirect does not match variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the code:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}             !^index\.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$                       index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

When I open the site and look at the index.php file, the GET variable "url" displays "index.php". I need it to display the URL I attempted to reach.

Ex:

> http://www.yoursite.com/fake/path/to/page

should become

> http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?url=fake/path/to/page

so that index.php can display GET variable

```
$_GET['url'] = fake/path/to/page
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}             !^index\.php
```

will always be true because the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will never start with `index.php` (it'll have a path in front of it). Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
```